# Configuring Monolog With "php://stderr" On Local Valet

Tags: php, heroku, monolog, laravel-valet

I'm doing local development on a PHP project that is hosted in Heroku. I'm using Laravel Valet for my local environment, but it's not a Laravel project.

[Heroku recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging#logging-using-monolog) writing to `php://stderr`.

When I execute this code...

```php
$logger = new Logger('clever_name', [new StreamHandler('php://stderr')]);
$logger->critical('Critical');
```

...I can't figure out where the log is being written.

I've found two log files used by Valet:

- `~/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log`
- `~/.config/valet/Log/php-fpm.log`

Calls to `error_log()` write to `php-fpm.log`. What is `php://stderr` writing to?

Comment: It will most likely be defined by the PHP-FPM config.

Comment: @Sammitch - What setting should I be looking for that configures the target of `php://stderr`?